# How can I prove the following inequality? $ \tan( \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^3}} ) \leq \tan( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}} )$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, arithmetic

How can I prove the following inequality?

With $x \in\mathbb N $

$$ \tan( \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^3}} )  \leq  \tan( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}} )$$

I did the following :

$$ \tan( \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^3}} )  \leq  \tan( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}} )$$
$$\implies \arctan( \tan( \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^3}} ))  \leq  \arctan(\tan( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}})) $$
$$\implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^3}}  \leq  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}} $$
$$\implies  \sqrt{(x+1)^3} \leq  \sqrt{x^3}  $$
$$\implies  \sqrt{x^3} \leq  \sqrt{(x+1)^3}  $$
$$\implies  x \leq  x+1 $$

I know that tangent is not injective, but when working with natural numbers, does the inequality hold?

Comment: knowing tan(x) is an increasing function is enough , when the domain is natural (in this question) , tan takes input only in 0 to π/2 ... can you proceed ?

Comment: By the way your $\Rightarrow$'s should all be $\Leftarrow$'s. Also, your third last line is wrong and should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x)=\tan x$ is an increasing function for $x\in (0,
\pi/2)$
$f(x)=\tan x \implies f'(x)= \sec^2 x>0$
So for natural numbers $x$ $$(1+x)^{3/2} > x^{3/2} \implies \frac{1}{(1+x)^{3/2}} < \frac{1}{x^{3/2}} \implies \tan\frac{1}{(1+x)^{3/2}} < \tan \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}.$$

Edit:

Note that $$\frac{1}{(1+x)^{3/2}},\frac{1}{(x)^{3/2}}<\pi/2, \text{when}, x=1,2,3,4,...$$

Comment: Thanks, corrected now.

Comment: That wasn't correct, there was an error placing "$" sign, I have suggested edits please review

Comment: $tan(\frac{\pi}{4})= 1, tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4})= -1$

Comment: Here $x$ are natural numbers $ 1/(1+x)^{3/2},,1/x^{3/2}$ will always be acute angle for $x=1,2,3,4,5,...$  less than $\pi/2$.

Comment: Now , it's ok,,, before edit, you said , $tan$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$, that's why i devoted. So, (+1)

Comment: Thanks, you raised an important point.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function to both sides of an inequality and preserve the order as long as the function is strictly increasing. In this case arctan is strictly increasing in (0,$\tan( \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^3}})$) for $x \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0):

We know that, $n^{3/2}$ would increase as $n$ increases and $n>0$ this directly implies that the multiplicative inverse would necessarily decrease and close towards zero as $n$ approaches $\infty$.

Now, when the domain of $n$ is restricted to natural numbers, $n^{-3/2}$ will only take values in the range $(0,1]$.

Also, it is known that $1$ radian ≈ $57.3^\circ$, so we can say that as $n$ increases, the value of $\tan {n^{-3/2}}$ decreases towards zero (input of $\tan$ reduces gradually.

Hence proved.